# How do I inject a buffered reader into a class with a file reader as its parameter using Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-web

I have this spring boot application in which I have the below line inside a method.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somePath"));
```

How can I inject this into my code so I can mock it for my unit tests? Using guice I could use a provider. But how can I achieve this using spring boot? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock the class which  have the below line inside a method.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somePath"));
```

Create a Mock instance of the class and define the mock behaviour like :

```
@MockBean
private TestClass testClass;

when(testClass.readFile()).thenReturn(content);
```

where content is the output you want to return.

you can create a bean of buffered reader and inject :

```
    @Bean
BufferedReader reader(@Value("${filename}") String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{

    return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
}
```

-Dfilename=SOMEPATH

Comment: I need to read this file line by line, therefore there is no readFile method. This line inside another method which does some processing on the read file. So this is not possible. Are there any ways to inject the BufferedReader into the class I'm using?

Comment: create a bean of bufferedreader @Bean
 BufferedReader reader() throws FileNotFoundException{
  return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
 } and inject it

Comment: File Name is given as a command line parameter. Currently the controller class implements CommandLineRunner and gets the parameter. How to associate that to this bean method?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bean like below.

```
    @Bean
    public BufferedReader bufferedReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somePath"));
    }
```

Now you can inject it in your class.

```
    @Inject
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
```

To take filename from properties, create a foo.properties file inside resources directory And then do this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class SampleConfig {
    @Value("${fileName}")
    private String fileName;

    @Bean
    public BufferedReader bufferedReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Foo.properties:

```
fileName=file_name
```

Comment: File Name is given as a command line parameter. Currently the controller class implements CommandLineRunner and gets the parameter. How to associate that to this bean method?