# How do I inject a BufferedReader with InputStreamReader as its parameter using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito

My question is along the same lines as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171280/how-do-i-inject-a-buffered-reader-into-a-class-with-a-file-reader-as-its-paramet). However, my BufferedReader takes an InputStreamReader as parameter. My code looks like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/endpoint");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//Line of importance:
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
```

How do I inject this, so that I can mock it for unit testing? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added test code (how I think it should work):

Adding a bean(?):

```
@Bean
public BufferedReader bufferedReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader());
}
```

Mocking of all dependencies with mock instances:

```
@Mock
private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

@Mock
private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

@Mock
private InputStream inputStream;

    when(URLhandlerClass.getPath(any(String.class))).thenReturn("http://localhost:8080/endpoint);
    when(bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn("firstLine", "secondLine", "thirdLine");
    when(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
```

ERROR: FileNotFoundException and Connect: connection refused

Comment: When only works on mocks, you do not have any mocks, therefore it cannot work.
I would not bother to unit test those four lines - it's difficult and essentially tests framework code, which is seldom useful. 
Of more interest is the code which does something with the content, e.g. the code you do not have shown which reads the BufferedReader.

Comment: @ChristianSauer I updated code with Mock instances. Thanks for the contribution, you are right that it tests framework code. However, my endpoint only have one entrance (one public method) and to test all the rest of the code, I would have to mock out the above framework-code, so that it can proceed to the "content" code.

Comment: Having only one entrance is normal. But your problem is that your code is a monolith. Use a Service or something like this to divide your code into testable components. Your problem is not the framework code per se, but that your code is not designed for testability

Comment: E.g. if oyu have a /post method on your controller,your coulde SHOULD look like this:
BufferedReader data = dataService.GetBufferedReader(...)
dataProcessor.processData(data)

Comment: @ChristianSauer All right, that makes sense. Thank you for walking me through it a bit =)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly do you want to mock?
Easiest I see here is to fake the whole method, e.g. wrap everything in a service and mock it whole when testing your code.

e.g.

```
@Service
public class DataReader {
    public BufferedReader ReadDataFrom(string url){
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/endpoint");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //Line of importance:
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    }
}
```

This can easily be faked.
Usually, when you encounter a problem where you ask yourself "wtf I mock this?" the solution is a service ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I still don't understand how I can mock test it. I know it's also confusing for you since I don't know how to test it, but I think I need to mock BufferedReader with parameters. I will add my idea to the OP